# Formik - Is there a way to get fresh values object on Form change?

Tags: formik

I have a Formik form with onChange handler:

```
<Formik initialValues={values}>
  {({ values }) => (
    <Form onChange={() => passUpdatedValues(values)}>
    // ...
    </Form>
  )}
</Formik>
```

`values` is an object with multiple properties, and Form's inputs are responsible for each of those properties. Parent component of this one uses those values to compute other stuff, and I want to pass the whole updated values up there on each field change.
.
With current approach it will pass an outdated obviously (the values right before onChange event fired).

I can manually create an object to pass, taking `e.target.value`, but it's kind of messy and grows the code base a lot, especially when there are many fields in the form.

My question is if there is a simple way to get updated `values` after onChange event, from that handler?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I've found so far, looks like there are no any updatedValues prop in Formik.

```
<Form
  onChange={e => {
    values[e.target.name] = e.target.value
    passUpdatedValues(values)
  }}
>
```